# Is it grammatically correct to say ( can I kindly bring your attention to .... )?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, adverbs, descriptive-grammar

Is it grammatically correct the position of the adverb in the following question ( can I kindly bring your attention to .... ) ?

Comment: Yes, but replacing "can" with "may" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: We don't usually describe our own actions as kindly. We ask if someone would kindly do something for us, but we don't offer kindly to do something for *them*. The politest form would be 'May I draw your attention to...' or 'I wonder if I might draw your attention to...' If you **really** wanted to attribute kindness to them you would have to say something like, 'Would you be so kind as to allow me to draw your attention to...'!

Comment: Don't vandalise content. If you want to delete it, please register your account, or flag the question for moderators to delete it for you.